# Need to trim underscore from last character in string

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'm in need of assistance for the best method to remove an underscore from a derived string in Python 2.7. 
I have a series of filenames I'm parsing, and the first portion gives information on the type of file.  I need that data to match with a database entry.
Here's the rub, the regex findall strips the period, but the trailing underscore remains.  As such, I can't get a 1:1 match in the database.

```
tmr_ba_incr_2016091500.csv
orm_160915.csv
TXT_MNG.160916.done
```

The findall gives me 3 elements in the output;

```
tmr_ba_incr_, 2016091500, csv
orm_, 160915, csv
TXT_MNG, 160916, done
```

The first element needs to have the ending underscore dropped.
I can't find a way to do this effectively.

```
tmr_ba_incr_ should be tmr_ba_incr
orm_ should be orm
TXT_MNG should be TXT_MNG
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd strip off the filetype with [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext)

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.splitext("tmr_ba_incr_2016091500.csv")
('tmr_ba_incr_2016091500', '.csv')
```

This is the standard way to deal with finding file extensions.

Then I'd just check that the last character was an underscore and remove it if it was:

```
>>> def remove_last_underscore(iterable):
...     if iterable[-1] == '_':
...         return iterable[:len(iterable)-1]
...     else:
...         return iterable
... 
>>> remove_last_underscore("this_has_trailing_underscore_")
'this_has_trailing_underscore'
>>> remove_last_underscore("asda_asd_as")
'asda_asd_as'
```

Comment: This works fantastic, but I prefer the method above.  Still, this works and is solid.  Thank you

Comment: And I would prefer shuttle87 method because it can be easily understood, contrary to my regexp. See my updated answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way of removing last underscore from string is using regular expression.

```
import re

my_string = 'abc_'
re.match(r'^(.*?)_?$', my_string).group(1)
```

Here I match whole string (thus ^ and $) against pattern that allows me to extract all characters lazily (`.*?`) before last optional underscore (`_?`).

Characters are matched lazily (`.*?` instead of `.*`) so that last underscore does not match.

---

Please note that above method is just a regular expression trick. In fact if I needed to solve this problem in real system maintained by different people I would prefer shuttle87's solution because it is simply more transparent.

It simply reads:

```
if last character is '_':
    return new string without trailing character
else
    return original string
```

There is a famous quote from Jamie Zawinski:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

In our case this applies as well. Understanding the regular expression that I proposed requires more advanced knowledge of regular expressions. Beginner programmers might have lots of problems with reading it.

So you should treat my suggestion as a regular expression exercise, not a "clean code" solution to be applied in real systems :)

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I need.

Comment: Great that I could help. If you find this anwer helpful you might consider upvoting it :)